# How to calculate conditional expectation?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

I want to calculate the conditional expectation $E(X|Y)$, assuming $X(x)=x^2$ and $\{Y=y\}=[\frac{y-1}{4},\frac{y}{4})$ for $y=1,2,3,4$ with $P(Y=y)=\frac{1}{4}$ on the probability space $\left([0,1), \mathcal{B}^1_{|[0,1)}, \lambda^1_{|[0,1)}\right)$.

I am trying to solve it as follows:

By the definition of conditional expectation, 
\begin{align*}
E(X|Y=y) &= \sum_{i=1}^4 x_i \frac{P(X=x_i,Y=y)}{P(Y=y)} \\
&= 4 \sum_{i=1}^4 x_i P(X=x_i,Y=y) \\
&= 4 \int_{\{Y=y\}} X dP \\
&= 4 \int_{[\frac{y-1}{4},\frac{y}{4})} x^2 dP 
\end{align*}

I have to stop here. Because I don't understand how to integrate $x^2$ over $[\frac{y-1}{4},\frac{y}{4})$ with $dP$. Is the $P$ defined by $P(X=x^2,Y=y)$ and what is this? Can you show me a sketch of $X$, $Y$, and $E(X|Y)$ on $[0,1)$?

Comment: The measure $P$ is the third entry of the triplet $$\left([0,1), \mathcal{B}^1_{|[0,1)}, \lambda^1_{|[0,1)}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the probability space is the unit interval with Lebesgue measure, the integral $dP$ is just normal calculus integration: $$\int_{[\frac{y-1}{4},\frac{y}{4})} x^2 dP=\int_{(y-1)/4}^{y/4}x^2dx.$$

---

Looking at it again, your derivation is flawed. The equation $E[X|Y=y] = \sum_{i} x_i P(X=x_i,Y=y)/P(Y=y)$ is only valid when $X$ is a discrete random variable. This does not apply here, since $X$ is continuous.

What you instead want is 
$$
E[X|Y=y] = \frac{E[X1_{\{Y=y\}}]}{P(Y=y)}=4\int X1_{\{Y=y\}}\,dP=4\int_0^1 x^21_{[(y-1)/4,y/4)}\,dx=4\int_{(y-1)/4}^{y/4}x^2\,dx
$$
The first equality is the definition of the conditional expectation of a (general) random variable on an event. The third inequality follows from the substitutions $X=x^2,\{Y=y\}=[(y-1)/4,y/4)$, and $dP=dx$.

Comment: Do you mean $E(X|Y) = -4 \int_{y-1/4}^{y/4} x^2 dx$? Why is there a negative sign? In fact, I am still confused about the step from sum to integral.

Comment: The negative sign was my mistake, fixed. The calculation I wrote was meant to be appended to the work you’ve already done. I’ll edit in some explanation about the sum to integral step